# Does Microsoft still support SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does Microsoft still support SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

Mainstream Support ended on 10.04.2018. The extended Support for SP1 will end on 11.04.2023. See the [Microsoft Prduct Lifecycle page](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-ch/lifecycle/products/sharepoint-server-2013) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The mainstream support end date of SharePoint 2013 SP1 is 4/10/2018 and the Extended Support End Date is 4/11/2023.

The detailed guideline of policy is here:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/product-servicing-policy/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2013?redirectedfrom=MSDN

You can always check the life cycle here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=SharePoint%20Server%202013